# Controlling an element's behaviour based on scroll with framer motion

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, framer-motion

please I would like to know if it is possible to link values an element on the page should animate to based on how far you have scrolled, with framer motion.

For instance, let's say I have a tree picture beside a bunch of text, how do I do this such that as I scroll down that particular section, the tree's opacity or height increases, and if I scroll up the page the reverse occurs.

So if you have scrolled 50% of the section, the opacity of the tree will be 0.5. Let me try to represent this in code the best way I can.

```
<div className='flex justify-between'> // tailwind styling
 <img src='/treeImage.png' />
 <p>Some bunch of text...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You'd use [`useElementScroll`](https://www.framer.com/docs/motionvalue/##useelementscroll) or [`useViewPortScroll`](https://www.framer.com/docs/motionvalue/##useviewportscroll) to get the scroll position as a [Motion Value](https://www.framer.com/docs/motionvalue/). You can then use that value to animate the properties of the `motion.img` of the tree. Most likely you'd use [`useTransform`](https://www.framer.com/docs/motionvalue/##usetransform) to map the scroll values to the properties of the image you want to change.